# Not able to access WSO2 IS 5.9.0 GUI console from dns mapped to it?

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am not able to use my WSO2 IS 5.9.0 GUI console from the Domain i have mapped with ec2 instance IP. The management console login screen opens up but after entering the credentials it show 403 Access DOMAIN was desnied.

What might be the reason behind this? Please Help.....

What Changes Do I Need To Make In Deployment File?

And I am setting up my WSO2 to production can anyone please send me an example of any good deployement.toml file.....so that i can ensure production level quality?

Comment: use https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.9.0/administer/deployment-checklist/ documentation for production-level guidelines. There should be some logs in the regarding the 403 error please add them as well

Comment: Sir can you help me with main problem that is very important .......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are not fronting with any load balancer, the following changes are enough.

- You need to change the server's host name. hostname property can be
  configured  in the deployment.toml file
- Change the CN name of the SSL certificate to be equal to the
  hostname. Changing the CN name of the certificate is done for
  SSL hostname verification.
- If you are trying from the local machine, do a mapping of the
  hostname to ec2 instance ip

Please follow this documentation to refer how to change hostname. https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.9.0/setup/changing-the-hostname/

If you are using any loadbalancer, you may need to change proxy port also. Please refer to this documentation, if you are using any load balancer https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.9.0/setup/deployment-guide/